# Universal quantifier quantifying every object in the domain

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

Every person likes all food" and ∀x ∀y (P(x) ∧ F( y ) ∧ L(x,y))

When we have a universal quantification, it imposes that all objects of the domain has a certain property. Is there a way to rewrite this to make the predicate logic formula true?

For example:  Every person likes all animals

P(x) -  x is a person

A(x) -  x is an animal

L(x,y) - x likes y

∀x ∀y (P(x) ∧ A( y ) ∧ L(x,y)).

This answer is *not* correct, because the use of the universal quantifiers in the formula imposes that all objects are person and animal. Is there a way to make the formula correct?

Comment: Hint: Remember that "$P(x)\implies Q(x)$" is true whenever $P(x)$ is false.

Answer (score 4):

The formula you gave litteraly says "everyone is a person and everyone is an animal and everyone loves everyone".

The formula expressing "Every person likes all animals" would be :
$$\forall x \, \big( P(x) \longrightarrow (\forall y \, A(y) \longrightarrow L(x,y) \big) $$
This formula is equivalent to $\forall x \,  \forall y \, \big(P(x) \longrightarrow (A(y) \longrightarrow L(x,y) \big) $, or even to the more readable:
$$\forall x \, \forall y \, \big( (P(x) \wedge A(y)) \longrightarrow L(x,y) \big) $$